# Retrofit - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY Error

Tags: java, android

I am making a call to a server using Retrofit and getting a json response. The error I'm getting is:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

This is my code

```
Main method,


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<Movie> movieList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org").build();

        api movieapi = restadapter.create(api.class);

        movieapi.getData(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Movie> movies, Response response) {
                movieList = movies;

                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,movieList);
                //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Interface api

```
public interface api {

    @GET("/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=e2a804764747474747474574817b218e")
    public void getData(Callback<List<Movie>> response);

}
```

class adapter

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Movie> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv.setText(movie.getTitle());
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+movie.getPoster_path()).into(img);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Movie class (Where I handle the getters setters for json)

```
   package com.wuno.moviesapp.model;


public class Movie
{
    private String vote_average;

    private String backdrop_path;

    private String adult;

    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String original_language;

    private String overview;

    private String[] genre_ids;

    private String original_title;

    private String release_date;

    private String vote_count;

    private String poster_path;

    private String video;

    private String popularity;

    public String getVote_average ()
    {
        return vote_average;
    }

    public void setVote_average (String vote_average)
    {
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
    }

    public String getBackdrop_path ()
    {
        return backdrop_path;
    }

    public void setBackdrop_path (String backdrop_path)
    {
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    }

    public String getAdult ()
    {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult (String adult)
    {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getOriginal_language ()
    {
        return original_language;
    }

    public void setOriginal_language (String original_language)
    {
        this.original_language = original_language;
    }

    public String getOverview ()
    {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview (String overview)
    {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String[] getGenre_ids ()
    {
        return genre_ids;
    }

    public void setGenre_ids (String[] genre_ids)
    {
        this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
    }

    public String getOriginal_title ()
    {
        return original_title;
    }

    public void setOriginal_title (String original_title)
    {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }

    public String getRelease_date ()
    {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date (String release_date)
    {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public String getVote_count ()
    {
        return vote_count;
    }

    public void setVote_count (String vote_count)
    {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
    }

    public String getPoster_path ()
    {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path (String poster_path)
    {
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public String getVideo ()
    {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo (String video)
    {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public String getPopularity ()
    {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity (String popularity)
    {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Movie [vote_average = "+vote_average+", backdrop_path = "+backdrop_path+", adult = "+adult+", id = "+id+", title = "+title+", original_language = "+original_language+", overview = "+overview+", genre_ids = "+genre_ids+", original_title = "+original_title+", release_date = "+release_date+", vote_count = "+vote_count+", poster_path = "+poster_path+", video = "+video+", popularity = "+popularity+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrofit tries to parse the result to the type you've specified, and this is not the type that is returned. The list you've specified is a member of the object that returns.

Comment: @UdiIdan : shouldn't you bee carrying this kind of conversation over to the chat? And do you think this is really a good question, 20 comments in?

Comment: I answered, though again I'm without android studio at the moment, so there might be errors. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit tries to parse the result to the type you've specified, and this is not the type that is returned. The list you've specified is a member of the object that returns.

You should create an object for the response:

```
public class MoviesResponse {

     private int page;
     private List<Movie> results;
     private int total_pages;
     private int total_results;

}
```

And change your callback:

```
@GET("/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=your_api_key")
public void getData(Callback<MoviesResponse> response);
```

Comment: And this would take the place of my current Movie class right?

Comment: No, Movie class is needed for List<Movie>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I understand the basics of what your saying but I am going to have trouble implementing this throughout. Do you know how somewhere online I could go read to be able to fix this with your answer? For example when you change the type from list in the interface all the place it is called a list in main have errors, so list just needs to be removed then getters and setters need to be made in the new class you suggest is my understanding here.

Comment: No something specific, but there's a lot of info about it, just google it. If you still have problems, I will try to help tomorrow when I'm on my laptop.